# Get the values from $i , with disturbed order

Tags: php, sql, forms, for-loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) 
   {
    //some output ommited

        <td><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='$name[$i]'></td></tr>";
    }
```

> $name[$i] = name1,  name2,  name3 , name4 , name5 , name6

Now  once the button is  clicked, this is what I should be displaying.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['name1'])) {echo "name1 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name2'])) {echo "name2 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name3'])) {echo "name3 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name4'])) {echo "name4 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name5'])) {echo "name5 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name6'])) {echo "name6 selected";}
```

I have option in the db to enable or disable any name. If name3 is disabled ,  the sequence/ordering of `$i` will change.and I am not able to display the required parameter w.r.t `$i`.

For exmaple I want to display , with name3 disabled:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['name4'])) {
    echo "$name[4] selected, kind is $kind[4] kind and type is $type[4]";
}
```

with name3 disabled , name4 will display values from name5

2:

How to get the values of Request with $name[$i]

```
for loop () {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['$name[$i]'])) {echo "name1 selected";} 
}
```

Help me device an algo to get the values of `$i`, so that even if the order is disturbed , i should know `$i` is carrying which value.

Comment: that's pseudo code, *right Sam?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- ,, right, Thats pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to concat `$i` to `name` to get unique names:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) 
{
   echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='$name . $i'></td></tr>";
}
```

If `$name` is "name" then you will get "name1", "name2", "name3", etc.

Then you can `print_r($_REQUEST)`; to see the items submitted.

You do not need a for loop to see which of the items is set, but if you want to loop through the REQUEST array you could do something like this:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $post_var) 
{
    if('name' == substr($post_var, 0, 4))
    {
        echo $post_var . ' ';
    }
}
```

Result:

> name1 name2 name3

Comment: Values are passed correctly as I mentioned in the code

Comment: if (isset($_REQUEST['name1'])) {echo "name1 selected";} .... How to write this with $name ..if (isset($_REQUEST['$name[$i]'])) {echo "name1 selected";}

Comment: A. You never indicated that and 2. Then what are you asking?

Comment: I have just written a sample code that I am using , and required output that I should be getting,  B: I have edited the question with 2nd part

Comment: You do not need a for loop to see which is set @moonakhan