# validate the form with variables, php

Tags: php, sql, forms, for-loop

I have asked a question here 
[Get the values from $i , with disturbed order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091062/get-the-values-from-i-with-disturbed-order/36091398?noredirect=1#comment59829938_36091398)

Below is rephrased version of this question.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($offername); $i++) 
       {

echo "<tr><td>$name[$i]</td><td>$kind[$i]</td><td>$type[$i]</td>
<td><input type='submit' value='Purchase' name='$name[$i]'></td></tr>";
        }
```

> **$name[$i] = name1,  name2,  name3 , name4 , name5 , name6**

```
How do I validate the form w.r.t  $name[$i]. [ name='$name[$i]' ]

if (isset($_REQUEST['$name[$i]'])) {echo "$name[$i] selected";}
```

> This isset gives me no output.

But If I use the values stored with in $name[$i] , it works fine.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['name1'])) {echo "name1 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name2'])) {echo "name2 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name3'])) {echo "name3 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name4'])) {echo "name4 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name5'])) {echo "name5 selected";}
if (isset($_REQUEST['name6'])) {echo "name6 selected";}
```

**Desired Output.**

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['$name[$i]'])) 
            {
         echo "$name[$i] selected , Kind: $kind[$i] type= $type[$i]" ; 
            }
```

Comment: is this ` echo "$name[$i] selected , Kind: $kind[$i] type= $type[$i]" ;` inside a for loop???

Comment: Yes , it will be placed under foor loop, but at first , I need to Validate the form. Its does not give me any values.

Comment: mentioned in question.

Comment: can you show the code where $`name[$i]` is declared?

Comment: @SergeyRonin lol and the irony is the poster is same

Comment: its not duplicate, I have mentioned in the question already.

Comment: Please read the question ,, I have mentioned , Its rephrased version.

Comment: @moonakhan If you want to rephrase a question, please edit your original question. It is not a good idea to create a new question when you are asking the same thing again. So, I believe, this question is a duplicate which have to be deleted. I've found a link to your previous question exactly after carefully reading this question, just for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

if `$name[$i]` is an `array` ie, `[name1, name2, name3 , name4 , name5 , name6]` the you can do:

```
foreach($name[$i] as $name){
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {echo "$name selected";}
}
```

or else if `$name[$i]` is a `string` ie, `name1, name2, name3 , name4 , name5 , name6`
you can explode it first using `$name[$i]=explode (',',$name[$i])` and then use the same `foreach` loop mentioned above

or `if your question is wrong` and `$name[$i] is just a reference to $name array` you can do something like:

```
for($i=0 ;$i<=count($name);i++){
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name[$i]])) {echo "$name[i] selected";}
}
```

Comment: I have tried 2nd part of your question , It gives me strange out put, it echos, only odd $i values.  i.e it shoes only 1, 3, 5, and does not show 0,4,6.. .. strange !!!! 2: this is what i have tried ........ for($i=0 ; $i<count($name); $i++){
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name[$i]])) {echo "$name[$i] selected";}
}

Comment: same output with forearch() ,, as suggested by you.

Comment: that means only `1, 3, 5` is set and `0,4,6` is not set

Comment: I have seperate submit button for each $name. if i try the same with values ,it works fine. 2: like this ....... if (isset($_REQUEST['name1'])) {echo "name1 selected";} ... it will show all as set.

Comment: got it , part of code from <form> was changed , so it was not showing for even values, it works fine . let me set it fully, then i will accept this answer ..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['$name['.$i.']'])) {echo "$name["'.$i.'"] selected";}
```